# Best method of pushing content changes that contains paragraph fields from dev to production?

Tags: 7, entities, paragraphs, deployment, staging

I manage a very big site with over 30k nodes and these nodes have many fields in them including paragaph fields with many sub fields in them too. Currently when testing and adding in content. I have to manually input them into the dev site and once the client approves, I have to manually do this again on prod. The import feeds module doesnt support paragraphs and neither do others from what I researched.

What would be the best method of deploying content changes from dev to prod that contain paragraph fields data?

Comment: The traditional model is to develop content on the prod site only and code on the dev site and pull them together in test. It's not very practical to control content with version control. You can then refresh your dev with the database from prod periodically. If your client needs to approve the content, first, why not give them mock ups or allow them to see it before it's published or create test content on the test site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One recommendation is to use "Features" to generate:

1. a Feature export of any config changes to the content types, paragraph bundles, and fields
2. a separate Feature export of the content/nodes themselves

To accomplish this, you'll need:

- "Features" module:  https://www.drupal.org/project/features
- "Features Extra" module:  https://www.drupal.org/project/features_extra
- "UUID  Features" module:  https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid_features
- "Strongarm" module:  https://www.drupal.org/project/strongarm
- "Diff" module: https://www.drupal.org/project/diff

NOTE:  this approach generally works well, as long as the effected content/node IDs between production and your staging/dev environment are the same.

Comment: I thought features as only for config change migrations. I dont think you can do node content. Can you? What if my content contains a video or image? I doubt a features module would make sense in that scenario.

Comment: With the UUID Features & Features Extra modules installed, you can also export/import content.

Comment: what about a 50MB video file or a 5MB image file? how does it handle that during export / import?

Comment: You might need to manually edit the content and upload/reattach file attachments for any individual file fields.  If the files are simply linked by url reference, you can manually rsync/copy/ftp the file assets from your local dev environment to the same folder location on production.

Comment: That doesnt seem streamlined at all. All my user files are uploaded via amazon S3. So its a bit tricky

Comment: You might be able to get the content (without files) migrated using Features, and then using Feeds/Feeds Tamper update those nodes with the files from your fileserver, since each node will have the same UUID.